# How to accumulate a calling setter method with a variable inside it as argument?

Tags: java, methods, setter, getter, getter-setter

Here is my call to a setter method `setNumber()`, with a variable inside it as an argument, but I want to accumulate the setter method as well and then add this `storeNum` variable, which means that the instance variable inside the setter method will get accumulated value and include `storeNum` value as well.

**Expected output:** `setNumber(storeNum) = setNumber(storeNum) + storeNum`

**NOTE:** I have the same class. Also, I can directly access the instance variable, instead of calling the `setNumber()` setter method and can easily do this thing like `this.number += storeNum`, but I want to call the setter method accumulate and add `storeNum` variable value. Is it possible?

> EDIT:

Here is `setNumber()` code:

```
public void setNumber(int inputNumber) 
        {
            this.number = inputNumber;
        }
```

Comment: can you post code for setNumber()

Comment: @Gaur93, I have posted the code.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, maybe you could post some numbers to illustrate, maybe http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#addAndGet-int-

Comment: @TitanicLover did you not get your answer or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Gaur93, My instance variables were kept as private but you made it static and int. Is there any other way? Anyways, much appreciated for your answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static data member for accumulation. For example:

```
class test{
static int a=0;
int b;
public void set(int b)
{
this.b=a+b;
a=a+b;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

test t1=new test();
t1.set(4);
System.out.println(t1.b);
t1.set(5);
System.out.println(t1.b);
}
```

This will produce following output :

```
4
9
```

Now whenever you use set method the result will be accumulation of previous values

Comment: Conside decorating static int a to volatile else your code might break in multithreaded environment